# Is it possible to create a device that can decode the EM waves generated from an electronic machine?

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, signal-processing, radiation

I recently watched a movie in which the hero (a robber) invents a device that can capture and decode the EM waves generated from an Automated Teller Machine (ATM) during its use. The movie claims that since the ATM is an electronic device, EM waves (corresponding to each digital operation in the ATM) are generated during its use, which can be captured and decoded to get the account details of a customer while he uses his ATM card to withdraw money.

Is it really possible to make such a device? What are the practical hurdles? Or is it theoretically impossible to decode the EM waves generated from an ATM?

Comment: Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking. Hopefully ATMs are adequately shielded.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks, that was informative. I thought the leakage emissions would be unintelligible to decode into anything meaningful.

Comment: IDK about ATM machines, but the cryptography world devotes a substantial amount of mind-share to understanding and either disabling (if you're a white-hat) or exploiting (if you're a black-hat) so-called [_side channel attacks_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack). Those include _anything_ that comes out of the machine (radiation, fluctuations in power consumption, changes in timing,...) that could possibly give away some clue to its internal state.

Comment: You'd probably have to OWN one of the ATM's, so you could take some time characterizing it.  You're not gonna just walk up to some machine, stick a sensor on it, and have at it.   Let's hope the ATM your bank uses isn't available on Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely as the EMI radiated would have a useful signal from reading mag cards and keystroke signals that would be so far below the noise radiated by the CPU and power supplies that it would all be noise.

I have done Tempest testing (at many FCC sites and Burroughs' EMI lab in Paola Pennsylvania) and radiation testing on magnetic disk drives with 1kW from DC to 100 MHz to attempt tampering and also sniffing data to prove they are inert to attacks except on a long interface cables. In a shielded case the signals are unusable with shielded cable with ambient CPU noise.  But we could detect pixels on a high res. Hitachi CRT being tested next to us using VGA BW over 200MHz.

One thing I learned is that at the 1/4 wave resonant frequency of the faraday cage for testing susceptibility that the E field sensors used for feedback can get a Ricean null and then the 1kW driver goes to max and the amp starts humming.

Nice try.

At one time the encrypted satellite smart cards could be jammed with special code to cause it to reset and during its reset time special boot loader code on startup could bypass the encryption routine from starting up and branch to get free DTV. People would line up for blocks to get cards programmed for $75 for get free DTV for a period of time until they fixed the loophole. Guys got rich for a 1 minute fix. Imagine $75/minute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I've seen a demonstration of the display of a CRT being reproduced on listening equipment picking up the RF emitted from the display at a considerable distance. Whether modern LCDs transmit as much display-related energy as the old fashioned cathode ray equipment is another matter.

Way back in my early career (now retired), I worked to modify one of our microwave spectrum analysers to have a 200 MHz IF bandwidth rather than its stock 100 MHz, for [Tempest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)) use by a government customer. It was 30 kg of 19" rack machine, so I guess they were using it to harden their own equipment rather than to actively spy on other people in the field, though you can get a lot of gear inside a van if you want to do the latter.